# Java lists filter and find first/find last

Tags: java, performance, optimization, collections, java-8

I have a java list of objects. The object attributes are:

```
public class CheckPoint {
    private String message;
    private String tag;
}
```

Now, I want to find the filter the list based on tag and get first/last element.

For eg: Possible tag values: A, B, C. For tags with value **A** - I want the last element, and **B** - I want first element, **C** - first element

Current Solution:

```
CheckPoint inTransitCheckPoint = checkPointsList.stream().filter(c -> c.getTag().equals("A")).reduce((first, second) -> second).orElse(null);

CheckPoint useCheckPoint = checkPointsList.stream().filter(c -> c.getTag().equals("B")).findFirst.orElse(null);

CheckPoint typeCheckPoint = checkPointsList.stream().filter(c -> c.getTag().equals("C")).findFirst.orElse(null);
```

However, I do understand this is an inefficient solution since we are looping thrice. Can someone help me solve it in a more performant way?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: How big is `checkPointsList` in the worst case and are you experiencing any actual performance problems?

Comment: If you want code clarity, Streams are fine. If you want performance, a `for` loop might be more adapted *in this use case*.

Comment: You really should just use a good old fashion for loop and reduce overhead by over 3... Just create the initial variables before the for look and have 3 if statements. I completely disagree with other posters who say to only change it if you have performance issues. This is how you end up with performance issues. Alternatively, if you really want to use streams, you can likely use forEach...

Comment: *"this is an inefficient solution"* Not really. The looping itself is fairly small compared to the rest. If you're looking for micro-optimizations at that level, you should use a `for` loop, not streams, since the overhead of a single streaming far outweighs the performance of 3 `for` loops, let alone a single `for` loop gathering all 3 results. In short, "inefficient solution" is incorrect and you should move on with the code that makes the most sense to you, until code profiling shows you actually have a problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, looping through the same list three times to find the first occurance of three different items is insanity, there is no reason to move on to other things considering he is actively asking about this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest grouping the `checkPointList` by tag into a `Map<String, LinkedList<CheckPoint>>`:

```
Map<String, LinkedList<CheckPoint>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", new LinkedList<>());
map.put("B", new LinkedList<>());
map.put("C", new LinkedList<>());

for(CheckPoint c : checkPointList) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(c.getTag(), ignored -> new LinkedList<>()).add(c);
}
```

The linked list is a handy helper because it allows you to directly get the first or last element (and if absent returns `null`):

```
CheckPoint A = map.get("A").pollLast();
CheckPoint B = map.get("B").pollFirst();
CheckPoint C = map.get("C").pollFirst();
```

---

Or you can just use this even easier `for-loop`:

```
CheckPoint a = null, b = null, c = null;
for (CheckPoint checkPoint : checkPointList) {
    String tag = checkPoint.getTag();
    if ("A".equals(tag) && a == null) {
        a = checkPoint;
    } else if("B".equals(tag)){
        b = checkPoint;
    } else if("C".equals(tag)){
        c = checkPoint;
    }
}
```

The variables for `"B"` and `"C"` are always overwritten with the last value, whereas for `a` only the first `"A"` checkpoint will be chosen.

Comment: @Eugene I've though a bit about which collections should be used, maybe a `Queue` would be better, one which only keeps the last added element and another one which keeps the first added

Comment: @Eugene feel free to include an approach with an arraylist in your answer. I don't think that using an `ArrayList` would improve my answer greatly. It is more memory efficient, but this shouldn't make a big impact in most environments

Comment: Is it the classical trade-off between time and space? My original solution is seemingly inefficient because it streams thrice, whereas yours uses a map and three more lists? Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: @SwapnilBagadia correct, I've updated my answer with an easier solution using just some `if-else`s and 3 variables, which should be fastest

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is the best solution, which I could not think of. Simple for loop saves the day.

Answer (score 2):

You could first collect to a `Map` for example:

```
Map<String, List<CheckPoint>> map = 
       checkPointsList.stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CheckPoint::getTag));

Optional.ofNullable(map.get("A"))
        .orElse(Collection.emptyList())
        .reduce((left, right) -> right)
        .orElse(null);
// same for "B" and "C"
```